# RStudio/Shiny - Google Cloud SQL - pgAdmin = App not connecting to db, works locally

Tags: sql, r, database, google-cloud-platform, shiny

Using [this article](https://medium.com/@cshiva/connecting-to-gcps-cloud-sql-postgressql-from-pgadmin-3-simple-steps-2f4530488a4c) I connected pgAdmin to my Google Cloud SQL. Using the Code

```
library(DBI)
library(dplyr)
library(RPostgres)

con <- dbConnect(
       RPostgres::Postgres(),
       host = "3x.xx.xx.xx9",
       port = 5xx2,
       dbname = "dbname",
       user = "postgres",
       password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
   )
```

I connect to the database as it appears in pgAdmin no problem, then developed a Shiny app locally, works just fine running from RStudio (runapp). Published to a *shinyapps.io*. I dont believe host=localhost, so I'm confused why the app wont connect/pull data for data visualizations from db.

Originally the code above was in the header (outside ui and server of Shiny app) and the app would timeout before displaying the dashboard. I moved this code segment into the server logic and the dashboard will display correctly but plots relying on the SQL db connection wont display and dont even display an error, just blank where the plots should be.

ANY help appreciated.

ps - I'm a mathematician, not well versed in computer science lingo or any networking stuff... this foray into SQL and database connections alone was a stretch for me... If you can, explain it like I'm a poor lil undergrad :)

pps - im pretty sure I *dont* want to open my pc to the internet, or mess with firewall stuff. please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the article you provided, there's one requirement for you to communicate with your Cloud SQL instance locally and that is to authorize your public IP address in Cloud SQL.

This is similar and should be done as you will have to allow and authorize certain shinyapps.io IPs for it to communicate with your Cloud SQL instance.

To explain why, your client application's IP address or address range (on your case, shinyapps.io) must be configured as [authorized networks](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/authorize-networks#authorized-networks) when you're connecting using the public IP address of your Cloud SQL instance. This is a security design so unauthorized applications can't access your database easily.

The IPs that you need to allow can be seen from RStudio's [support page](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/217592507-How-do-I-give-my-application-on-shinyapps-io-access-to-my-remote-database-). I will list it here:

```
54.204.34.9

54.204.36.75

54.204.37.78

34.203.76.245

3.217.214.132

34.197.152.155
```

To summarize, all you have to do is to follow the same instructions on configuring authorized networks, just in this case, you will have to add multiple IP's coming from shinyapps.

Comment: This worked! I used the website I linked and you referenced, added each IP in CIDR form, i.e. 34.197.152.155/32, and it looks like it is going through (new error now but that's on my end)! I really appreciate you pushing me in the right direction, and what an easy solution! Here I was messing with pg_hba.conf lol. Thank you Donnald with two n's!!